# What happens when you calloc a struct containing an enum type?

Tags: c, enums, calloc

```
typedef enum { false, true }bool;

struct { bool value_set; int value; }
```

What happens when this struct is allocated using calloc? Will the enum hold false as the 
default value? Since calloc sets the memory to 0.

Comment: Yes. But you knew that, didn't you. You were looking for a link to the official reference?

Answer (score 0):

An enum is integral type. If you don't assign them values, they start at 0 and increase. Therefore your typedef is equivalent to

```
typedef enum { false = 0; true = 1; } bool;
```

Therefore calloc will set `value_set` to zero which is equal to `false`.